# BASH Variable Placeholder Substituion

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have the following script per say.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Define the variable placeholders
NAME=[[NAME]]
SAYS=[[SAYS]]

echo "$NAME says $SAYS"
```

This is say a setup script which sits there and awaits for variables to be replaced so it can be queued and run along with many more of the same scripts.

How would I replace the variable placeholders from a controlling script?

Comment: As always, what have you tried?

Comment: The obvious answer is sed, however I was just wondering if there was a better way, the current method is to use EOF to write everything to the file within the controlling script code and all.

Comment: sed, awk, python, perl will all work. Another "better" approach is to put the variables in a separate file that this script sources.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something, it depends on how you plan to drive it.  One possibility is to create a driver script that simply sets the environment variables before calling the script:

```
file: so.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$NAME says $SAYS"
```

then in a driver script:

```
$ NAME=dog SAYS=woof ./so.sh
dog says woof
```

Comment: @FredrikPihl: <grin> thanks.  I notice you gave a correct answer in the comment while I was typing in the same answer.